# jQuery ajax problems

Tags: jquery

I am writing some functionality using jQuery that i normally handle with a page refresh/form submission.

Basically I am submitting a form using jQuery's ajax.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){


    $("#show-comment-form").click(function(event){
        var ret =  $.post("post.php", $("#comment-form").serialize(), "", "html");
        $("#theComment").html("<strong>" + ret +"</strong>");
    });
});


</script>

</head>
<body>
Testing Stuff
<br /><a href="#" id="show-comment-form">Insert New Message</a><br />

    <div id="comment-form">
        <form name="form" id="form">
            <span>Enter Your Question Here</span>
            <textarea id="comment" name="comment"></textarea>
        </form>

    </div>

    <p id="theComment">

     avsailable
    </p>    


</body>

</html>
```

The object returned is an XMLHttpRequest.  Do I manipulate this object or is it something that I probably do not need.

My problem is I want to have a user post a response using a form on a webpage but do it without a page reload and prepend html onto the beginning of all the other user responses. The page the form is posted to prints out some HTML but I cannot get that HTML to appear on the page because the response is a XMLHttpRequest object. I'm kind of lost.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the [callback](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post#callback) function parameter:

```
$("#show-comment-form").click(function(event){
    $.post("post.php", $("#comment-form").serialize(), function(ret){
      $("#theComment").html("<strong>" + ret +"</strong>");
    }, "html");
});
```

That function will be executed when the asynchronous request ends, and its first parameter is the data returned from the server.

Answer (score 2):

Specify a function as a third parameter and the data should be returned in a callback:

var ret =  $.post("post.php", $("#comment-form").serialize(), function(data) { 
$(data).appendTo('body');
});

You shouldn't need to interact with the XHR object. For more info:

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post